How can I use vasp for calculating different cell volumes by adjusting cell parameters
I am new to VASP. For my system, I am using single-layered perovskite LSCF (La-Sr-Co-FeO3), (La-Sr-Ni-FeO3) LSNF, and I want to change my system's cell volumes w.r.t cell parameters. Is it possible I searched I find I can change cell volume by ISIf tag when ISIF=8 w.r.t cell shape and volume but for different volumes, can I perform that?

+1. Welcome to our community!

what do you want to do? relax keeping shape fixed but changing volume? or do single-point calculations at fixed volume? please explain in more detail what your goal is.

Generalized optimization in computational materials science involves adjusting both atomic positions and simulation cell parameters to minimize the system's energy/forces/stress. The goal is to reduce the forces acting on individual atoms and the stress within the simulation cell to achieve the ground state configuration, where the system is at its lowest energy and most stable configuration.
In the VASP, the ISIF tag plays a crucial role in controlling which degrees of freedom (DOFs) are considered variable during the optimization process. The ISIF tag determines whether the optimization affects only the atomic positions, the cell shape, or the cell volume, depending on the chosen value.
If the system has a well-defined symmetry, manually setting the appropriate lattice parameters can preserve this symmetry throughout the simulation. This avoids unnecessary relaxation steps and reduces computational cost. However, careful consideration of the material's structural characteristics and a thorough stress check after the calculation are necessary to ensure accurate results.

